# Is this CSS selector correct?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

It doesn't seem to be working. The styles of nth-child(2) need to be differnt on hover if nth-child(3) is .active

CSS:

```
li:nth-child(3).active ~ li:nth-child(2):hover
```

HTML:

```
 <ul>
    <li>
      <h1 id="logo">Logo</h1>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>

    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Parts</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Resources</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: The styles of nth-child(2) need to be differnt on hover if nth-child(3) is .active

Comment: If you want to select LI, that stays immediately before LI.active, I think it's impossible. You can do that with jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to select `li:nth-child(2)` only when `li:nth-child(3)` is `.active`, it's not possible, because the sibling combinators `+` and `~` don't look backward.

You have to either modify your HTML to somehow accommodate these conditions, or use DOM traversal (much easier).

Comment: there is now way to look backwards with css?

Comment: @kreutz: Nope, no way at all.

Comment: The problem with using li:nth-child(2):hover is that if li:nth-child(3) is .active the styles are different on hover.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the active li and apply a hover, this selector is sufficient:
`li.active:hover`

here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/QWzYj/)

If you want to select the li before the active li, you are going to need to use JavaScript.

Another option is to recognize which li is the one before the current active li while rendering the JSP (or your technology of choice) page and give it the appropriate hover.